# Is the output of MySQL's INET6_ATON() compatible with PHP's inet_ntop() function?

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL's INET6_ATON converts a ipv4 or ipv6 address into a binary representation. PHP's inet_ntop() is supposed to read a binary representation of ipv4 or ipv6 address and convert it into a human-readable form. But an old comment on php.net says they are incompatible:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inet-ntop.php#117398
Both PHP and MySQL have gone through several iterations since that comment 6 years ago, so I don't know if this incompatibility remains (or if was ever even present).

I don't know how to copy binary data directly from MySQL to PHP, so I translated the binary into hex first. Here is what I have done so far:

```
SELECT HEX(INET6_ATON('::1')); # gives 00000000000000000000000000000001
```

I placed the output of that into PHP'sinet_ntop():

```
var_dump(inet_ntop(hex2bin('00000000000000000000000000000001'))); # gives ::1
```

It appears to work, but the comment still worries me, because of my lack of knowledge of how to test this without first doing hexadecimal conversions and lack of familiarity with ip addresses.

Can PHP always run inet_ntop() on the output of MySQL's INET6_ATON() successfully?

Comment: What is the reason to convert the address on MySQL side if you need to revert this operation immediately after receiving the output? simply retrieve it without any convertion...

Comment: @Akina I store IP addresses in a VARBINARY(16) column (which is often recommended for storing both ipv4 and ipv6 addresses) and I don’t want MySQLto do all the work of translating from binary to a human-readable IP because MySQLis a bottleneck for me. I am not translating it back immediately.